# Which is better? - Querying database every time or keeping objects in session

Tags: database, jsf, session

I have two pieces of code which basically do the same thing. I fill a datatable in two different ways. Here are they:

```html
<h:dataTable  binding="#{currentUser.ITEMS}"   style=" width:505px;"   id="userTable" value="#{currentUser.items}" var="user"  >
    <h:column>

    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Account Number</f:facet>
             #{user.name}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Currency</f:facet>
            #{user.surname}
    </h:column>                
</h:dataTable>
```

where items is an array that contains the user's items and where currentUser is a session scoped class object of type User. In the first code, when user logins, i get all its items from database, and add them to session to use later, as i fill the table in this way. Now the second version:

```html
<h:dataTable  binding="#{user.ITEMS}"   style=" width:505px;"   id="userTable" value="#{user.items}" var="user"  >
    <h:column>

    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Account Number</f:facet>
             #{user.name}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Currency</f:facet>
            #{user.surname}
    </h:column>                
</h:dataTable>
```

In the second example, i do not keep the items list when user logins to the system, but whenever a table is to be filled, i do the database query and fill the table by the items of the user.

So my question is, which way is better? I see that in the first case it may be harmful to use a lot of session objects but also in the second case everytime we need items info we do a database search. So can we say that one way is better than the other in terms of space, time etc?

Comment: You shouldn't cache in JSF. You should cache in JPA. Do not abuse HTTP session to act like a DB cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caching data in a session scoped object runs the risk of providing stale data - if another process modifies the database's contents then the session scoped object won't reflect these changes.  It doesn't sound like this is mutable data, though, in which case this isn't a problem.

Other than that, caching data in the session scoped object may be better in terms of time since the data is kept in main memory, and going to the database each time may be better in terms of space since you're not keeping the data in memory.  The "may" qualifiers are there because the database may be caching this data for you.

Comment: thanks, and you are right whenever an update is done on items, i need to create new item, add it to items arraylist and then replaces the old object in the session with the new one, it is hard to provide stale data